# javascript only closest element from a function call

Tags: javascript, element, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to find a way to get an element by className closest to the function is being called on document load.

I found .closest() but it requires an element selector.

As function is being called randomly and don't have a specific location on DOM.

So if I could get element of the current running function script tag

I know document.currentScript but apparently its not working inside a function:

https://jsfiddle.net/ow240m2p/

also script.length - 1 is getting wrong elemnt as function is being called after document load:

```
var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1];
```

I could assign ID to the script tag but I am trying to find a way without ID

Comment: this is confusing, you want to get the last js function been called?

Comment: What do you mean with the wrong element "function is being called after document load"? 
Please take a look to this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/s4oznyoz/1/

Comment: I updated your example: https://jsfiddle.net/s4oznyoz/3/ the problem I am facing is that it if test1() is called then nearest is "My Div" not "Second Div" @DanielH closest element of the function being called